# service doesn't work in Lollipop

Tags: android, service

I tried to make some apps with service (for backsound), I tried to run app in my phone but there are no problem, but when my friend run my app, it doesn't work, my phone is Jellybean and my friend's is Lollipop.

This is my code activity:

```
package com.example.michael.fordear;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.example.michael.switchcard.R;

/**
 * Created by Michael on 19/11/2015.
 */
public class frag1 extends Activity
{
    ImageView iv;
    MyTimer tim1;
    MyTimer1 tim2;
    MyTimer2 tim3;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    BackgroundSoundService sv;
    Intent svc;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.frag1);

        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.open);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.open);

        svc=new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
        tim1 = new MyTimer(5000,10);

        tim1.start();
        startService(svc);



    }

    public class MyTimer extends CountDownTimer
    {
        public MyTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() // Jika waktu sesion habis
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ms1);
            tim2 = new MyTimer1(35000, 10);
            tim2.start();
            Log.d("TAG", "fin");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

    }

    public class MyTimer1 extends CountDownTimer
    {
        public MyTimer1(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
        {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() // Jika waktu sesion habis
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ms2);
            Log.d("TAG", "fin");
            tim3 = new MyTimer2(6000, 10);
            tim3.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

    }

    public class MyTimer2 extends CountDownTimer
    {
        public MyTimer2(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
        {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() // Jika waktu sesion habis
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.end);

            Log.d("TAG", "fin");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
        onStop();
        finish();
    }
}
```

and this is the service

```
package com.example.michael.fordear;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;

import com.example.michael.switchcard.R;

/**
 * Created by Michael on 19/11/2015.
 */
public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service
{

    private static final String TAG = null;
    MediaPlayer player;
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cobamp3);
        player.setLooping(false); // Set looping
        player.setVolume(100, 100);
    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();
        return 1;
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TO DO
    }
    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TO DO Auto-generated method
        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {

    }
    public void onPause() {

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {

    }
}
```

So my friend can run my apps in his Lollipop Android?

Comment: What is the problem which you are facing? If there is a crash you should give us the logcat.

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal the music didn't play, when apps run, the music should be played, but it didn't at my friend's phone.. my friend's phone is Lolipop, my phone is Jellybean

Comment: Did you check for exceptions, what did you do for debugging the issue?

Comment: do you declare service in your `manifest`?

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal hhmm, I didn't, because there are no problem when I run app in my phone (Jellybean) and also I can hear the backsound. But when I sent my apk to my friend, and he ran it in his' (Lolipop), indeed the apps run, but there are no backsound.

Comment: @KingfisherPhuoc Yes I have declared it, mate

Comment: @MichaelSetyadarma So you have not checked your code for exceptions, and have not debugged it. Yet you expect us to help you do it. Dude, this is not how SO is supposed to be used. Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask